# Getting Exc_Bad_Access in sqlite3_prepare_v2 irregularly

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, crash, exc-bad-access

Before inserting into livecategories, I am checking this id is exists if not then insert the value. But sometimes it crashes and get exc_bad_access. Why I am getting this? Please see attached image.

[image]

when I hover on &statement then it showing this 0x000000:

[image]

Comment: just above crashed line: sqlite3_stmt *statement;

Comment: Do you finalize your statement?

Comment: Yes, but after inserting into database.

Comment: Can you try putting "NULL" instead of nil. Looks like there is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below sample code:

```
// Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init the animals Array
    animals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from animals";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row
                NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
                Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc] initWithName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl];

                // Add the animal object to the animals Array
                [animals addObject:animal];

                [animal release];
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Another [Link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/adding-data-using-sqlite-for-iphone/) for help.

Hope it works for you..